# Picture file showing random image

Tags: file, png, code-injection, gif, photo

It's a general question, so I'd be happy with a general answer!
Is there a way to inject code to a graphics file, .gif , .png etc etc so when the user opens the file, each time the result,what you see, could be randomly different?
 For example a black dot on a white background that each time the file opens, the dot will be in a random place inside the picture.
Thanks
- Not talking about animated picture files, but a static image that could have random changes each time opened.
- I don't expect answers containing code, a general guideline would be great.

Comment: Animated graphics, depends (.mng lends itself to this sort of thing). Static files. Probably not as that would really not be their nature. You need to be more specific to the file type, context, and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Not unless deliberately invoking undefined behavior (e.g., buffer overruns to embed executable code inside the image).